# How can I add categories-authors-members area for commenting on my website?

Tags: php, html, css, posts

I have designed my own template on dreamweaver using HTML and CSS.
I don't know much about php which i assume its what i need.
but i still want to know how to make something has similar idea like http://howtogeek.com
I mean the posts and commenting and the author's thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like http://disqus.com/

It requires no programming on your end at all and allows users to share there thoughts on your content.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying it now (:

Answer (score 0):

You need to know relational database for this job. you can learn mysql which is the query language for relational database. If you are serious, you read this book visit [http://www.amazon.com/Database-System-Concepts-Abraham-Silberschatz/dp/0073523321](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523321). But you need learn PHP for handle your database schema. For quick start you should visit http://w3schools.com